# Excel to DataGridView with OleDbConnection using two DataAdapter

Tags: vb.net, winforms, connection, database-connection, oledb

1- Create **C:\Book1.xlsx** file into **C** disk.

2- Ensure that you have one sheet in the **C:\Book1.xlsx** file named **Sheet1**.

3- Fill **Sheet1** cells from **A1** cell to **E20** cell with some data.

4- Close **C:\Book1.xlsx** file.

5- Put one **DataGridView** into the **Form1** and named it as **DataGridView1**.

6- Run code in order to see if you are able to get excel data to **DataGridView** correctly.

As you can see I have used two **OleDbDataAdapters** in order to get excel data to **DataGridView**.

I have prefer to use two **OleDbDataAdapters** because I come across *out of memory exception* if excel data is so big.

If you examine my code you will see that **myDataAdapter1** gets excel data from **A1** cell to **E10** cell.
and **myDataAdapter2** supposed to get excel data from **A11** cell to **E20** cell.

If you examine my code you will see that I tried to merge two **DataTables** and bind to **DataGridView1.DataSource** with no success.

Please correct my codes and show me how to merge two **DataTables** and bind to **DataGridView1.DataSource**?

I want to get excel data from A1 cell to E20 cell and put the DataGridView1 by using two DataAdapters and two DataTables.

If I use one data adapter then my app crashes with big data.

So I try to use two data adapters and two data tables.

Comment: Remove `Xml` from the extended properties. Are you sure you don't have a Header in that excel sheet? The DGV columns will be named `Column1` etc. Your DataAdapter fills the taget object using just `myDataAdapter1.Fill(DataSet1)`. Since you're not, apparently, using the DataSet, you could directly fill a DataTable. You need just one DataAdapter and one DataSet/DataTable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The grid must first add columns to accomadate the data. Then add the rows in a While loop. I only have 3 columns in the test data from Excel.

```
Private Sub PrepareGrid()
    DataGridView1.Columns.Add("col1", "Column 1")
    DataGridView1.Columns.Add("col2", "Column 2")
    DataGridView1.Columns.Add("col3", "Column 3")
End Sub

Private Sub FillFromExcel()
    Dim FileName As String = "Book1.xlsx" '"C:\Book1.xlsx"
    Using cn As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & "Data Source=" & FileName & ";" & "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=NO;IMEX=1"";")
        Using cmd As New OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$];", cn)
            cn.Open()
            Using reader = cmd.ExecuteReader
                While reader.Read
                    DataGridView1.Rows.Add(reader(0), reader(1), reader(2))
                End While
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    PrepareGrid()
    FillFromExcel()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

`DataTable.Merge` cannot work without a Primary Key. I fooled around with `DataTable.Load(IDataReader)` but that must use Merge underneath. So, you can either add a Primary Key to the Excel worksheet (just sort of a row number column) and set the appropriate properties in code or manually loop through the second DataTable adding the records to the grid. (slow)

Here is a slightly different method of filling the grid with all the data. I don't have a large Excel worksheet to test. It might address the memory problems but I am afraid it will use the same methods underneath.

```
Private Sub FillFromExcel()
    Dim FileName As String = "Book1.xlsx" '"C:\Book1.xlsx"
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Using cn As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & "Data Source=" & FILENAME & ";" & "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=NO;IMEX=1"";")
        Using cmd As New OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$];", cn)
            cn.Open()
            dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader)
        End Using
    End Using
    DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
End Sub
```

Comment: My code uses a DataReader. You could try an OleDbReader and write the records directly to the grid in the While loop. Having both the grid full of records and the DataTable in memory kind of doubles the usage.

Answer (score 0):

You can go from an Excel file to a DGV, like this.

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Dim MyConnection As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection
        Dim DtSet As System.Data.DataSet
        Dim MyCommand As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
        MyConnection = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source='c:\vb.net-informations.xls';Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;")
        MyCommand = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [Sheet1$]", MyConnection)
        MyCommand.TableMappings.Add("Table", "Net-informations.com")
        DtSet = New System.Data.DataSet
        MyCommand.Fill(DtSet)
        DataGridView1.DataSource = DtSet.Tables(0)
        MyConnection.Close()

    End Sub
End Class
```